# GraphQL validation not working as expected

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I am using PHP 8.1 with Symfony 6.1.x, Api-Platform 3.0.3 and have two entities:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CustomerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CustomerRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/customers/{id}',
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['customer:read'],
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['customer:write'],
    ],
)]
class Customer
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    #[Groups(['customer:read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write'])]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'customers')]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write'])]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    private ?CustomerAddress $address = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?CustomerAddress
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(?CustomerAddress $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CustomerAddressRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CustomerAddressRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/customer-addresses/{id}',
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['address:read'],
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['address:write'],
    ],
)]
class CustomerAddress
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write', 'address:write'])]
    private ?string $street = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write', 'address:write'])]
    private ?string $zip = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write', 'address:write'])]
    private ?string $city = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'address', targetEntity: Customer::class)]
    private Collection $customers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet(string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZip(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zip;
    }

    public function setZip(string $zip): self
    {
        $this->zip = $zip;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Customer>
     */
    public function getCustomers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->customers;
    }

    public function addCustomer(Customer $customer): self
    {
        if (!$this->customers->contains($customer)) {
            $this->customers->add($customer);
            $customer->setAddress($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCustomer(Customer $customer): self
    {
        if ($this->customers->removeElement($customer)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($customer->getAddress() === $this) {
                $customer->setAddress(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see the address column is not required (it's nullable). When I use the graphql endpoint from api platform I can not store a customer without the address:

```php
// This works
mutation createCustomer {
    createCustomer(input: {
        name: "My new customer"
        address: {
            street: "Street"
            zip: "12345"
            city: "City"
        }
    }) {
        customer {
            id
        }
    }
}

// This doesn't work (no address given)
mutation createCustomer {
    createCustomer(input: {
        name: "My new customer"
    }) {
        customer {
            id
        }
    }
}

// Error: Field createCustomerInput.address of required type createCustomerAddressNestedInput! was not provided.
```

Whenever I use the REST endpoint of api platform, it works as expected (no address will be inserted into the database, but the customer will be created).

Is this a bug in api platform or am I missing anything? How can I declare the `address` as nullable in graphql?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't found a solution. At the moment there are several bugs in API Platform 3.x Graphql so I decided to switch back to REST until the graphql endpoints are working as expected.